# use button click event to load usercontrol

Tags: asp.net

Now I am trying to use a button on the parent page to a usercontrol.

There is a checkboxlist on the usercontrol, and its datasource is read from database

the checkboxlist didn't load correctly. it is like:

> OnlineRenewa_draft1.tbl_LanguageChoices   OnlineRenewa_draft1.tbl_LanguageChoices OnlineRenewa_draft1.tbl_LanguageChoices
>   OnlineRenewa_draft1.tbl_LanguageChoices   OnlineRenewa_draft1.tbl_LanguageChoices OnlineRenewa_draft1.tbl_LanguageChoices

is it about postback issue? 
Any idea?
thanks

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (!IsPostBack) { 
            List<tbl_LanguageChoices> LanguageList = ((List<tbl_LanguageChoices>)Cache["LanguageChoise"]);

            otherlanguage.DataSource = LanguageList;
            otherlanguage.DataBind();
            otherlanguage.DataTextField = "Languages";
            otherlanguage.DataValueField = "GUID";
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to load the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're first databinding the checkboxlist's to the `DataSource` and then setting `DateValueField` and `DataValueField`. `DataBind` should be the last step.

```
otherlanguage.DataSource = LanguageList;
otherlanguage.DataTextField = "Languages";
otherlanguage.DataValueField = "GUID";
otherlanguage.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property of your `CheckBoxList`? You need to set it to the column/property of the object you have set as the datasource. Or as MSDN puts it:

> Gets or sets a string that specifies a property of the objects
>   contained in the list box whose contents you want to display.